# ? added to String Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am trying to rename a file using powershell

```
$oldPath="‪c:\users\guest\desktop\old.txt"
$newName="‪c:\users\guest\desktop\new.txt"
Rename-Item -Path $oldPath -NewName $newName -Force;
```

I am getting the following error

```
Rename-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '‪C' does not exist.
```

upon looking at the code in Notepad++ I realize there is a "?" appended in front of both the paths which is not visible in powershell ise.

The path visible in notepad++  `"?c:\users\guest\desktop\old.txt"`

I am unable to trim using  `$oldPath.TrimStart("?")` also

Comment: `Rename-Item -Path ($oldPath -replace "\?")` etc.

Comment: I found that the ASCII value of the invisible character is 8234 and I am able to trim $oldPath.TrimStart([char]8234)  this way. But just wondering what is causing this problem.

Comment: How did you enter the code in your Powershell? Did you do a copy/paste from somewhere perhaps? I see here[https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp] it is the unicode character for LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING

Comment: It's an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to clean up the path from special characters (as question mark is not visible in ISE it might be not a question mark but some special character). You could do it like this:

```
$oldPath = $oldPath -replace '[^\w\\:."]', ''
$newName = $newName -replace '[^\w\\:."]', ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can always put in a small function to remove invalid filename characters in your code, like this:

```
function Remove-InvalidCharacters ([string]$fileName) {
    $invalid = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars() -join ''
    $pattern = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalid)
    return ($fileName -replace $pattern, '')
}

$oldPath = Remove-InvalidCharacters "‪c:\users\guest\desktop\old.txt"
$newName = Remove-InvalidCharacters "‪c:\users\guest\desktop\new.txt"
if (Test-Path $oldPath -PathType Leaf) {
    Rename-Item -Path $oldPath -NewName $newName -Force
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Path '$oldPath' not found"
}
```

Comment: Since backslash is considered an invalid character, that will also be removed FYI.  You should skip the last two characters of that array

Comment: You're right. I have updated the answer now. Should have been _GetInvalidPathChars_ instead of _GetInvalidFileNameChars_